# After installing something, command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aptitude

Whenever I follow a step by step guide, I have this problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install something
$ sudo something
No 'something' command found
```

Something is installed, and I can find it with 'locate' after running 'updatedb'. But it is not being added to the PATH for some reason. Is this the normal behavior?

I'm on a Ubuntu 10 server edition box (virtualbox)

Answer (score 5):

Many commands are not in the PATH of a normal user, but are in root's path. You can either modify your PATH to match that of root's or preferrably, just specify the full path to the executable as such:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
No 'ifconfig' command found
$ sudo /sbin/ifconfig
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ dpkg -L something
```

It will shows all installed files by something package. Look for files that are on */bin/ directories.

Comment: Also, run `echo $PATH` to see if the installation paths shown by `dpkg -L something` is in the user's PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Commands that are run with `sudo` are run in their own environment. You can adjust the environment in /etc/sudoers via `visudo`. The PATH variable is called `secure_path`.